# Combining two column's data into one column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine Last name, first name and middle name into single sort name column in a SQL statement. Sometime middle name will be `NULL`, and if that's the case, the sort name is showing `NULL`.

How to handle this?

```
SELECT TOP 500
  Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name,
  [Last_Name] + ',' + [First_Name] + ' ' + [Middle_Name] AS SORT_NAME
FROM [dbo].[usr_CUSTOMER]
ORDER BY SORT_NAME
```

Results:

```
Last_Name  First_Name   MiddleName  Sort_Name
Aa         Robert       NULL        NULL
```

But I want to see sort_name to be `'Aa,Robert'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**COALESCE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
  COALESCE([Last_Name], '') + ',' + COALESCE([First_Name], '') + ' ' + 
  COALESCE( 
          [Middle_Name], '') AS SORT_NAME
```

Of course, this will leave ugly commas when last name or both first and middle are empty, so your actual code will need to be a bit more clever.

Comment: of course if you just include the comma as part of the `coalesce` you won't have that problem. eg `COALESCE([Last_Name] + ',' , '')`

Comment: true, but only if you assume middle name is the only _optional_ field. If you could have first but no middle or middle but no first, it just gets harder. The OP knows the rules of his data, that's why i left it to him. But your point is helpful, I should have included it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ISNULL()` function - it replaces a `NULL` value with something you define:

```
SELECT TOP 500 
    Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, 
    [Last_Name] + ',' + [First_Name] + ' ' + ISNULL([Middle_Name], '') as SORT_NAME   
FROM [dbo].[usr_CUSTOMER]  
ORDER BY SORT_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ISNULL function

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

Docs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Note that I moved the space separating First and Middle name inside the COALESCE so that you avoid having a trailing space when Middle name is NULL.

```
..., [Last_Name]+ ','+ [First_Name] + COALESCE(' '+ [Middle_Name],'') as SORT_NAME...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CONCAT(firstname,' ', LastName,' ', MiddleName) AS Full_Name
```

Comment: Add more details and explain the answer.